# Save object list in Xamarin Essentials

Tags: xamarin.forms

my first question is here

however since I was advised that questions should not change the original matter I created a new one.

I am saving user settings and I would like to save it in the list, I have had a look on setting by James however I found that that its not possible to save it in the list. So ia have decided to use Xamarin Essentials.

First I tried to save only a string value, which after some struggle I managed to work out and now I am trying to save an object

```
     static void AddToList(SettingField text)
        {
    
          var savedList = new List<SettingField>(Preference.SavedList);
          savedList.Add(text);
    
          Preference.SavedList = savedList;
        }
    
    
        private void ExecuteMultiPageCommand(bool value)
        {
        
          var recognitionProviderSettings = new RecognitionProviderSettings
            {SettingFields = new List<SettingField>()};
    
          var set = new SettingField()
          {
            ProviderSettingId = "test",
            Value = "test"
            
          };
         
           AddToList(set);
           NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMultiPage");
        }
    
    and then the sterilization and des
    
   public static class Preference
  {
    private static SettingField _settingField;
    public static List<SettingField> SavedList
    {
      get
      {
        //var savedList = Deserialize<List<string>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), "tesr"));
        var savedList  = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingField>(Preferences.Get(nameof(SavedList), _settingField)) ;

        SavedList.Add(savedList);
        return SavedList ?? new List<SettingField>();
      }
      set
      {
        var serializedList = Serialize(value);
        Preferences.Set(nameof(SavedList), serializedList);
      }
    }

    static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObject) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);

    static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

  }
}
```

But Preferences.Get doesn't take object, is there any other way how can I save my setting to a object list? Please advise

Comment: serialize/deserialize your object to a string if you want to save it in Preferences.  But Preferences is really designed for storage of simple data types, not complex objects.

Comment: ok, so do you recommend the Settings plugin?

Comment: I can't recommend anything because I really don't know what you're trying to do.  What is `SettingField` and why do you need a list instead of just storing discrete setting values?  Why not store them in SQLite instead of Preferences?

Comment: does sqlite have any perfomance downgrading?

Comment: I need a list because I am sending the data to provider.  Setting field contains string id and string value. Every time a call the provider service I need to send him the setting. and if I store it just like   public bool IsMultiPage
        {
            get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("IsMultiPage", false);
            set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("IsMultiPage", value);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [SecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android). You can save your strings only into it. So the place where you have serilized your object as json. Just convert your json to string with .ToString() and save it into secure storage.

You may continue saving your serialized json object as string in Shared preferences but it is recommended to use SecureStorage Instead.